# Syntax Highlighter that works in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know of a syntax highlighter that works with the HTML5 docType? I have tried several including SyntaxHighlighter, Snippet and a few others but none of them seem to be working correctly. I never usually have issues implementing plugins so I don't think it is something I am doing (although I never rule that out). Is anyone using one or another of these with HTML5 successfully? I know there area few of these post on here but none that were really recent.

I am looking to highlight mostly PHP, HTML and JavaScript syntax. I would prefer a jQuery solution but anything will do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) ?

It's easy to use, and the examples in the page are pretty good. I think something like [this](http://codemirror.net/demo/runmode.html) or [this](http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html) it's what you need

**EDIT**

I've used the first two in the past, but I think SyntaxHighlighter has better support:

[highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)

[chill (with jQuery)](http://noteslog.com/projects/chili/)

[Wrapper to SyntaxHighlighter in jQuery](https://bitbucket.org/larscorneliussen/beautyofcode/)

Comment: I looked into this some and i will have to try it out but it looks like a bit more then what I need I really just need to show the syntax code (for tutorials and stuff) this seems to be more for in browser editing

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the answer with a few more options that I've used, it's hard to know what to suggest because I don't really know why you can't get them to work

Comment: Oh @Gordnfreeman , another thing, if none of the options suit you, you could post some code so maybe we can figure out why it's not working

Comment: yeah Ill post some code, I have tried 4 or 5, no JavaScript errors on any of them. When I get a few minutes Ill post what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

You tried Google Prettify? I know that does a lot of languages, it might be up to date enough for HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Completely Unfair Comparison of JavaScript Syntax Highlighters](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/05/22/highlighters-comparison/en/) by Ivan Sagalaev, the creator of [Highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/). He favors his own, naturally, but is very upfront about it and the comparison is thorough.

Highlight.js' lack of line numbering is a deal-breaker for me personally, but otherwise it seems strong and does support HTML5 `<code>` tags rather than having to use `<pre>` by itself or `<script>` tags.